# Do R.Drawable elements IDs change on android when the app restarts or they are the same during the whole app lifecycle?

Tags: android, resources, storage, drawable

I'm concerned about storing the int value of a drawable ID on the phone storage, since it is not convenient to specifically reference the code "R.drawable.myimage" in some of my functions, due to dinamically assigned resources. Does it impact the reliability of the app when retrieving the resources, after it closes?

Comment: No, but it may change when you update the app.

Comment: **NEVER** touch the ids in R. And don't care for them. Enough said.

Comment: @njzk2 makes sense. I just confirmed what you said on debug. But didn't consider this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: @Rotwang I'll keep that in mind, thanks.